# What is the set of points of $\operatorname{Im}(z)=\frac15$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to describe the set of points of $\operatorname{Im}(z)=\frac15$.

So since $\operatorname{Im}(z)=y$. I have $1=5y$ and so $y =\frac15$.

So what does $y=\frac15$ represent?

Comment: So... are you saying you want to describe the following set?
$$\left\{z \in \Bbb C : Im(z)=\frac{1}{5}\right\}$$
Why are you dealing with $y$?

Comment: because y= Imz ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left\{\;z\in\Bbb C\;;\;\text{Im}\,(z)=\frac15\;\right\}=\left\{\;z=x+\frac i5\;;\;x\in\Bbb R\;\right\}$$

or in words: it is the set of all complex numbers with imaginary part equal to $\,\frac15\,$ . On the plane, this is the set

$$\left\{\;\left(x\,,\,\frac15\right)\;;\;x\in\Bbb R\;\right\}$$

It is a straight horizontal (i.e., parallel to the real axis) line

Comment: But Don ANtonio, Im(z)=y not x......gracias anyway

Comment: @ciuciu ,  If you write $\,z=x+iy\,$ then indeed $\,\text{Im}\,(z)=y\,$...what does this have to do with my answer, though?

Comment: Because you offered a complete different solution compadre..I thought that you might just explain me mine..because if Imz=1/5 then y=1/5..what does this represent on a plan? :)

Comment: @ciuciu, is **anything** in my answer that's unclear to you? There's written, clearly imo, that the wanted set is a straight line paralell to the real axis. What else do you want?

Comment: ....you aren't sweet/kind.But its fine.And don't bold your words.I can read.

Comment: I'm trying to be accurate and exact, and I don't think I'm being offensive or "bad". Being sweet is good for honey and treats, not for mathematicians. Can you see why my answer is correct and/or you think something's missing or unclear? For example, in what you wrote, it isn't clear what you called $\;y\;$ to, and somebody else brought this up. And I used bold letters to call your attention on something I thought was important, that's all.

Comment: Ok,I understand it now.We were both saying the same thing,just in different ways.And thank you.

Comment: Anytime, @ciuciu...

Comment: De nada hombre.